# Cleaning up my First Proof in Overleaf

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have just started working with Overleaf and would love it if anyone could point out what's messed up in my project, either in my proof itself or the Overleaf coding that causes it to look super weird in the document. I really have no idea how to use overleaf or do logic, so I hope what I did makes some sort of sense. I'm having some issues with text being italicized and having no spaces, and id love to figure out how to make it clear which assumptions I'm operating under through some sort of indicator to separate each of the derivations.

This is the project: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gyjkyhqtpnwy

The proof is for:

Problem 1.8. Using Definition 1.23, prove that ⟨a,b⟩ = ⟨c,d⟩ iff both a = c and b = d.

Definition 1.23 (Ordered pair). ⟨a,b⟩ = {{a}, {a,b }}.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please try to make your question self-contained.

Comment: In Overleaf click on the red number next to the Recompile button to get to the error log. Each error has a brief explanation, a link to a help page, and clicking on the error will take you to the LaTeX code that is causing problems. The main problems here are misuse of math-mode and math-mode delimiters, and also misuse of the \\. See here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions and here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/LaTeX_Error%3A_There%27s_no_line_here_to_end. To improve your question, maybe select one error that you don't understand and ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read an introduction in using math with LaTeX. Here is a part of your code. But I do not know where you want inline or display math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Suppose $<a,b>  = <c,d>$.   % $ is inline math      
We must show $a=c$ and $b=d$.
By definition of an ordered pair, we know

\[% is display math without numbering 
     \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}
\]

It follows that $\{a\} \in \{c,\{c,d\}\}$  and  $\{a,b\}\in \{c,\{c,d\}\}$

So, $\{a\}=\{c\}$ or $\{a\}=\{c,d\}$  and  $\{a,b\}=\{c\}$ or $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$


Assume $\{a\}=\{c,d\}$ and $\{a,b\}=\{c\}$ 

$c \in \{a\}$  and $d \in \{a\}$
 
so as $a$ is the only element in $\{a\}$ it follows $a = c$ and $d = a$ 

It follows $b \in \{c\}$ and as $c$ is the only element in $\{c\}$ that $b = c$ 

Since $a = c$ and $d = a$, it follows that $b = d$. Thus $a = c$ and $b=d$ 

\end{document}
```